# Maximize colorspace in seaborn palette

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to "maximize" the color space for a plot in seaborn. By that I mean I would like the color range to include the two extreme colors in a given palette.

For example if I choose the matplotlib color palette "YlGn_r" and plot it with pandas:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.plot(kind='bar', colormap='YlGn_r', width=.8);
```

[image: mpl_colors]

If I plot this with the same palette but seaborn the colors are different:

```
df['x'] = df.index
sns.barplot(x='x', y='value', hue='variable', data=pd.melt(df, 'x'), palette='YlGn_r')
```

[image: sns_colors]

I realize this is probably intended behavior, which I am not entirely opposed to, however is there a way to force `seaborn` to use the full spectrum? I have many plots that need the colors to match, some in `seaborn` and some with `matplotlib`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass a list of colors anywhere a palette name is accepted, so if you want specific colors, that's the best way to get them. One way would be `mpl.cm.YlGn_r(np.linspace(0, 1, 4))`.

However, `barplot` also desaturate the colors a bit, which looks better with large patches, but if you don't want that you can set `saturation=1`.

Comment: I was doing something similar to this, but this a bit more concise and straightforward, thanks.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use the same approach to get a set of "maximally" different colors (for an arbitrarily `high` number of colors) on a colorspace that is visually close (as in great for visualization) to `"Set1"` or `"Set2"` etc?